# How to discover , connect , send info and disconnect to all devices using wifidirect in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-wifi, wifi-direct, android-wireless

I am trying to create an android app which uses wifidirect to connect , send info and disconnect to al devices in the peerlist automatically.There is a service to do all this plus a broadcast receiver to handle wifip2p intents. Currently when peerlist is available app sleeps for 1200 ms then tries to connect, send info and disconnect to each device in the list.This events from sleep to disconnect happens in like a cycle.

The issue here is that devices gets connected often and the WiFi p2p connection changed intent is received but when checking if the network is  connected it retuns false so app can't send the data now. Thus sending data happens very rarely.

I don't see much information on the internet and I doubt that not many people have tried to implement something similar. Any information on how to do this would be a great help for me.

Any sample or pseudocode can be very helpful

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IIRC you can use _either_ p2p _or_ internet, but _not both_  -- at least so it was on first phone models with p2p.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Its working fine with ui controls for connecting manually but not working so when automated.

Comment: @18446744073709551615 can you tell me is it internet using WiFi or cellular internet that conflicts with p2p

Comment: What I have seen is that the same chip was using a different mac address for wifi p2p. In theory, newer phones could have double chips able to work on both channels. The Cellular internet (EDGE etc) should not be affected, if the software supports it. In general, different phone models (e.g. gs2...gs5 may show very different behaviour regardless of the Android version.)

Comment: What you can do is: download a communication application and decompile it (if your local laws permit it and you can have conditions under which the laws permit it). The reconstructed source will not compile, but you will see how p2p classes are used.